# DataAnnotation not popping the ErrorMessage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using Asp.Net 4 MVC 3.0 and Razor. I need to check the equality of two string. So I did this using Attribute for the class. I got the code from [here](http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/01/09/property-matching-with-data-annotations).
This is is how I used the attribute.

```
    [Match("FaxNumber", "ConfirmFaxNumber", ErrorMessage = "Fax number must match")]
    public class FaxModel
    {

        [Required, StringLength(maximumLength: 10, MinimumLength = 10),
        RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]( |-)?)?(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4})$",
            ErrorMessage = "Enter correct fax number.")]
        [Display(Name = "Fax number")]
        public string FaxNumber { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(maximumLength: 10, MinimumLength = 10),
        RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]( |-)?)?(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4})$",
            ErrorMessage = "Enter correct fax number.")]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm fax number")]
        public string ConfirmFaxNumber { get; set; }

     }
```

And here is the UI implementation of the two fields.

```
           <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="template">
                @Html.LabelFor(expression = (m => m.FaxNumber), labelText: "Fax number:") @Html.TextBoxFor(expression: expression, htmlAttributes: new { name = "FaxNumber", value = "${FaxNumber}" })
                <blockquote>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(expression)</blockquote>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="template">
                @Html.LabelFor(expression = (m => m.ConfirmFaxNumber), labelText: "Confirm fax number:")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(expression: expression, htmlAttributes: new { name = "ConfirmFaxNumber", value = "" })
                <blockquote>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(expression)</blockquote>
            </div>
```

In the above piece of code `expression` is `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<MyModels.Fax.FaxModel, object>> expression;`

Now the problem is that even if the values mis-match the error message is not bubbled up. I am not getting the reason for the behavior. Help needed.

Thankyou All.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already such attribute built-in ([`[Compare]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.compareattribute.aspx)):

```
[Compare("ConfirmFaxNumber", ErrorMessage = "Fax number must match"]
public string FaxNumber { get; set; }
```

The reason this implementation is not working is because it is a class level validation attribute which doesn't add a key associated to the error, so none of the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` helpers matches this error message. You will probably see it if you use the `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)` helper. But once again the `Compare` attribute is 
probably better suited to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @Darin. It worked but I am facing a new problem with the attribute. Once, the error message is popped to the screen, it does not reset. The error message gets stuck.  Every other attribute is working fine.